# Xcode 5.1 with new OS 10.10 Yosemite displays Cyan circle on screen

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I have installed the developer preview of the new operating system Yosemite. Xcode 5.1.1 and then I did the 10.10 update. After performing the update and restarting, when I open Xcode 5.1.1 I get this cyan circle with a cross hair in side of it. I cannot move it around nor close it.

Is there anyone that knows how to remove it or is experiencing the same issue.

My screen shot is available at this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK7JK.jpg

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 6 Beta.

Comment: I don't think it's Xcode specific. I selected the crosshair and noted that Preview was open. Closing Preview removed the crosshair so my guess is it's Preview related

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. I have upgraded to XCode 6 Beta 2, the the blue circle still appears when I open any xib file. Closing XCode 6 the circle will disappear. PLEASE HELP! This is killing my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a pre-release OS with a version of Xcode that doesn't officially support the OS Version so there is a good chance of you finding that things don't work as expected.

You should probably download Xcode 6 Beta 2 from the iOS/Mac Dev Centre and use that instead as it is designed for 10.10.

Xcode 5.1 is theoretically useless on the developer preview anyway as you cannot submit apps to the app store that have been compiled on a machine running a pre-release OS.

Comment: Actually, you can submit apps using Xcode 5.1 on Yosemite. (based on my own experience)